# ASP.NET 5 Empty App IRuntimeEnvironment Error

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-4.6

I have an ASP.NET 5 Beta 7 Application and it uses MVC but even when I comment everything out the appication throws this error. It worked fine one day and started displying this error the next. Any help or even pointers on where to look would be appriciated.

```
[InvalidOperationException: Failed to resolve IRuntimeEnvironment]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags hostingFlags, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +303

[HttpException (0x80004005): Failed to resolve IRuntimeEnvironment]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9924184
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +261
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the project.json file? Which runtime version you're using?

Comment: What does `dnvm list` resolve as well?

Comment: seems similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32425836/appdomaincreationexception-in-iis-express-using-asp-net-5-beta7

Comment: Yes dnvm list shows the proper version as default.

Comment: run `dnu list` and see if you have any dependency which is not beta7.

Comment: @Lukasz can you share the project.json and the result of `dnu list` with us?

Answer (score 0):

You probably ran the following command and got a new runtime:

```
dnvm update-self
```

Run the following command to set the runtime back to beta7 (even though it's outdated now)

```
dnvm use 1.0.0-beta7 -r clr -arch x86 -p
```

now you should be able to run

```
dnu restore
dnu build
dnx web
```